# Inconsistent <cword>, <C-R><C-W>, and keyword behavior

Tags: filetype-ruby, vi-words

I'm in a Ruby file, and because `!` is not an `iskeyword` character, if I place the cursor on a call to `mymethod!` and attempt a tag lookup via <kbd>C - ]</kbd>, Vim searches for `mymethod` (without the `!`). Adding `!` to the `iskeyword` option causes other problems, which I won't go into here.

Given the above behavior, I expected hitting <kbd>C - R</kbd><kbd>C - W</kbd> from command-line mode would insert `mymethod` on the command-line, but it actually inserts `mymethod!` (including the `!`). Running `expand('<cword>')`, on the other hand, results in `mymethod`.

What's going on here? The documentation describes <kbd>C - R</kbd><kbd>C - W</kbd>, saying:

> Insert the object under the cursor:
> ...
>
> CTRL-W    the Word under the cursor
> CTRL-A    the WORD under the cursor; see WORD

and `<cword>`:

> `<cword>`    is replaced with the word under the cursor (like star)

This is actually helpful in my case, as it means I can get tag lookups working correctly by putting the following in my `.vim/ftplugin/ruby.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer><silent> <C-]> :tag <C-R><C-W><CR>
```

But I'm curious where the nuanced behavior comes from and whether it's intentional, or whether it's likely to be fixed at some point, breaking my solution.

Comment: It is probably the result of the mappings in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ruby.vim`, which include a mapping of `<C-R><C-W>` to `<Plug><cword>` which is then mapped to a call to `RubyCursorIdentifier()`. That function contains expressions more complicated than I wished to follow, but it probably sees the `!` as belonging to the identifier `mymethod` and adds it to the result of `<C-R><C-W>`.

Comment: @garyjohn Wow, good find. It's definitely in there. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the result of the mappings in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/ruby.vim`, which include a mapping of `<C-R><C-W>` to `<Plug><cword>` which is then mapped to a call to `RubyCursorIdentifier()`. That function contains expressions more complicated than I wished to follow, but it probably sees the `!` as belonging to the identifier `mymethod` and adds it to the result of `<C-R><C-W>`.